# How to do this Ruby if-with-and in Python and not get list index out of range

Tags: python, ruby

In Ruby I can do something like:

```
irb(main):001:0> x = []
=> []
irb(main):003:0> puts "hi ho" if x.count > 0 and x[0]
=> nil
```

Ruby first evaluates `x.count >0` as false and does not bother to evaluate `x[0]`.

In Python I can have for example a file with:

```
x = []
if x.count > 0 and x[0]:
  print "hi ho"
```

When I run:

```
[onknows:/tmp] $ python test-if.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test-if.py", line 2, in <module>
    if x.count > 0 and x[0]:
IndexError: list index out of range
[onknows:/tmp] 1
```

So Python evaluates `x[0]` as well although there is no reason to evaluate it. Is there a way to use only one if and not resort to nested if in Python? I don't want to do something like:

```
if x.count > 0:
  if x[0]:
     print "hi ho"
```

Comment: `.count` is a *method*. In Python you always need calling parentheses with methods and functions. (Methods themselves are always boolean true.)

Comment: _"So Python evaluates x[0] as well although there is no reason to evaluate it"_ – nope, Python evaluates `x[0]` because `x.count > 0` returns `True`. Try to figure out why and you'll see what's wrong with your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> So Python evaluates x[0] as well although there is no reason to evaluate it.

I'm assuming this would work for you, in its most basic form:

```
if len(x) > 0: 
    print("Hi Ho!")
```

This evaluates the length of X, and (if greater than 0) responds True.

However, if the variable "x" does not exist, it will error. Evaluating if "x" exists at all, and contains at least one item, is (I assume) what you're trying to accomplish with ...

```
if x[0]:
    print("Hi Ho!")
```

Python will evaluate to `True` if the variable *exists* and contains any value. It will evaluate to `False` if the variable *exists*, but *does not contain a value*. Python will error if the variable does not exist.

So, this may be what you're looking for...

```
try:
    if len(x) > 0:
        print("Hi Ho!")
    else:
        print("Variable does not seem to contain a value!")
except (NameError, AttributeError, ValueError): 
    print("Variable does not exist!")
```

**EDIT:**

Note,that if `x` exists as a list, but contains no values, `len(x)` will evaluate to `0`. However, if you try to evaluate `x[0]` you will *still* get an error, but it is a `IndexError` rather than the "Variable doesn't exist" error.

Comment: OP's Ruby code also expects the existence of x; there's no need for the name/value error checks.

Answer (score 3):

Looks like you need `len`.

```
x = []
if len(x) > 0 and x[0]:
    print("hi ho")
```

Answer (score 0):

Python [supports short-circuiting on `and`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#boolean-operations-and-or-not) so if the first argument is `False` the second one is not evaluated.

`x.count > 0`  is always true:

```
In [12]: [].count > 0
Out[12]: True
```

You should replace it with `len(x)` and it works correctly:

```
if len(x) > 0 and x[0]:
  # ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Python does lazy evaluation on boolean expression when using `and` or `or`.

From the docs:

> The expression x and y first evaluates x; if x is false, its value is returned; otherwise, y is evaluated and the resulting value is returned.
>
> The expression x or y first evaluates x; if x is true, its value is returned; otherwise, y is evaluated and the resulting value is returned.

Python list method count() returns count of how many times obj occurs in list.

You should use `len(x)` to get the length of a list.

```
x = []
if len(x) > 0 and x[0]:
  print "hi ho"
```